# Number of ways of choosing x integers from 1 to n such that exactly y numbers of them repeats odd no. of times

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given $N$, $X$, $Y$

Find no. of sequences such that: 
1) Length of sequence is $X$ 
2) Exactly $Y$ number of integers from $1$ to $N$ repeat odd number of times in the sequence


Example:
$N=4$, $X=3$, $Y=1$ 
Then some possible sequences are:
$[1,4,4]$ 
$[2,2,2]$ 
$[3,1,3]$ etc.


An Invalid sequence would be :- $[1,2,3]$ as there are 3 integers which are repeating odd number of times.

**Note:** Order of elements in sequence matters 
 i.e. $[4,1,4]$ is counted as different sequence from $[1,4,4]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the Exponential Generating function or FFT.
For more information refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)

OR

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_combinatorics